# Reading File tags/properties in c++

Tags: c++, file, properties, filesystems

I know there are file comparison tools out there to determine whether files were added, deleted, or modified when comparing between two folders. However, I'm wondering how you would approach reading the file properties programmatically to see when the file is created/modified/accessed (like how you can find these information by viewing the file properties in a file explorere). Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the file info class of my current library of choice, for example:
[QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfileinfo.html)

Comment: That would require me to use the Qt platform, although that's another decision that I would have to consider when making my app cross-platform functional.

Comment: Qt was only mentioned as example. More or less every library that supports file handling will have similar functionality.in MFC it's CFile::GetStatus(..).

Comment: The link is not availlable

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you call [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() WinAPI function. On Linux it's [stat/fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).